# How can I collect I/O statistics on a ServerSocketChannel

Tags: java, io, nio

I've been learning how to use Java NIO for networking and I'm very happy with my results after the first few days. I've already converted my game to multiplayer and have tried it out with a few friends and I have to say it's a great feeling to accomplish something like that for the first time.

However, I've been doing a lot of research on the matter and can't really figure out the proper way to do it. I'm wanting to create a GUI that provides statistical information (Mainly for learning purposes). The information that I'm trying to access is pretty simple, and I know how to get most of it. The problem that I'm running into is gather networking statistics, rather, I/O data.

What I'm trying to do is display the amount of bits coming in and going out of the server every second. The information that I'm having a hard time finding is the following:

- How to get the current amount of data (In bits/bytes) being written and received through the `ServerSocketChannel`
- How to get the connection latency relative to a `Channel`

Thanks in advance for any nudges in the correct direction.

Comment: You can't. `ServerSocketChannel` doesn't do any I/O. It just accepts connections.

Comment: I guess, you are using `write(ByteBuffer[] srcs)` and `read(ByteBuffer dst)` methods for IO operations which return number of read/written bytes. You can just use these values for your statistics, right?